# Moving image relatively to cursor JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove, cursor-position

I am doing this small project - my cursor moves in a left rectangle and it should appear in the second one. I have made an image of cursor and I am trying to move it according to my cursor, but nothing happens. Could you help me to find the mistake? I would be very grateful!

Here is the code snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laboratory work 1_4</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        #imgc{
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="arrow.png" id="imgc" width="20" height="20">
    <canvas id="canvas"  width="800" height="600" ></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.rect(20, 20, 300, 200);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rect(350, 20, 300, 200);
    ctx.stroke();
    </script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js">
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#imgc").stop().animate({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    });
    </script> 
</body>
```

P.S. I added jquery library in a JavaScript libraries wizard in Netbeans. So the structure of my project looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You haven't include jquery.js in your page

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you mean like that? - `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js">`

Comment: Yep, exactly that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added it (edited my question), but it`s still not working

Comment: It needs to be it's own entity, separate from your JS code, eg `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script><script>/* your JS here... */</script>`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you very much ! I`m new to JavaScript, but it really helped me :)

Comment: No problem glad to help